# FabricJS Canvas with rounded corners

Tags: html5-canvas, fabricjs

How to I make a FabricJS canvas with rounded corners? I am looking to do this with the canvas itself and not the objects inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the CSS `border-radius` property on your canvas element:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('my-canvas');

// bigger pixels for more rounded corners
document.getElementById('my-canvas').style.borderRadius = '5px';
```

Or, in a CSS stylesheet:

```
#my-canvas {
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I have tried what you have suggested and your method leaves the corners of the canvas, while it makes another canvas with the rounded corners. Do you know how to remove the squares edges?

Comment: I meant the code to be an example, not code you should drop into your script. The argument passed to `fabric.Canvas` will be the `id` property of the created `<canvas>` element. In my example, I chose `'my-canvas'`. You really only need to add `document.getElement('whatever-you-created-fabric-canvas-with').style.borderRadius = '5px';`

Comment: I doubled checked by code again and I got it work. I was using your code as a guide and some how I missed a simple step. Thanks again for your help.